# Android: How to check does shared preferences exist, and how to delete them

Tags: android

To check does preferences exist I tried this way, but it shows null every time(maybe because I saved preferences in different view):

```
String def = null; 
String test = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString(PREF_GAME,def);
if(test == null) Log.v("main", "no saved data");
```

To delete preferences I tried editor.clear(), but it does't delete (however commit() every time return true):

```
   SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_GAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
   editor.clear();
   boolean tt = editor.commit();Log.v("DELETE PREF", String.valueOf(tt));
```

**UPDATE:** I found that if I check preferences exist in the same view, where i saved it, this checking works fine, but how can i do this in different view?

**Update:** I guessed with myself, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getSharedPreferences()` to get your preference.

**getSharedPreferences()** - Use this if you need multiple preferences files identified by name, which you specify with the first parameter.

**getPreferences()** - Use this if you need only one preferences file for your Activity. Because this will be the only preferences file for your Activity, you don't supply a name.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
public String prefGet(String id) {
    SharedPreferences opener = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String value = opener.getString(id, "Default");
    return value;
```